# Error producing to embedded kafka queue after upgrade from 0.7 to 0.8.1.1

Tags: java, junit, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka, jbehave

I haven't been able to find anything that directly handled the problem I'm facing, so I'm posting here. I have JUnit/JBehave tests that spin up an embedded ZooKeeper server, embedded Kafka server, and kafka producers and consumers.

After upgrading kafka from 0.7 to 0.8.1.1, I'm encountering the following types of errors:

```
ERROR [kafka-request-handler-5] state.change.logger - Error on broker 1 while processing LeaderAndIsr request correlationId 7 received from controller 1 epoch 1 for partition [topicName,8]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at kafka.log.Log.<init>(Log.scala:60) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.log.LogManager.createLog(LogManager.scala:265) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.cluster.Partition.getOrCreateReplica(Partition.scala:90) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$makeLeader$2.apply(Partition.scala:175) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$makeLeader$2.apply(Partition.scala:175) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:74) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
at kafka.cluster.Partition.makeLeader(Partition.scala:175) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$makeLeaders$5.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:305) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$makeLeaders$5.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:304) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.makeLeaders(ReplicaManager.scala:304) [kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.becomeLeaderOrFollower(ReplicaManager.scala:258) [kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleLeaderAndIsrRequest(KafkaApis.scala:217) [kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:189) [kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:42) [kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
```

and

```
WARN  [threadName] k.c.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread - [threadName], Failed to add leader for partitions [topicName,9],[topicName,3],[topicName,0],[topicName,8],[topicName,5],[topicName,1],[topicName,6],[topicName,2],[topicName,7],[topicName,4]; will retry
kafka.common.NotLeaderForPartitionException: null
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at kafka.common.ErrorMapping$.exceptionFor(ErrorMapping.scala:73) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.earliestOrLatestOffset(SimpleConsumer.scala:160) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread.handleOffsetOutOfRange(ConsumerFetcherThread.scala:60) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$addPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:179) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$addPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:174) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:224) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.addPartitions(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:174) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager$$anonfun$addFetcherForPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:86) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager$$anonfun$addFetcherForPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:76) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:109) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771) ~[scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager.addFetcherForPartitions(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:76) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:95) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:51) [kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar:na]
```

and

```
02/03 10:26:34.655 WARN  [kafka-request-handler-7] kafka.server.KafkaApis - [KafkaApi-1] Offset request with correlation id 0 from client clientName on partition [topicName,5] failed due to Leader not local for partition [topicName,5] on broker 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this has to do with the Time parameter in the new KafkaServer constructor.

I was passing in a null param for the [kafka.utils.Time](https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/kafka/utils/Time.scala) object:

```
private KafkaServer server = new KafkaServer(config, null);
```

Instead, you need to create an implementation of the kafka.utils.Time interface, and pass in a new instance of that:

```
private KafkaServer server = new KafkaServer(config, new SystemTime());

private static class SystemTime implements Time {

    @Override
    public long milliseconds() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public long nanoseconds() {
        return System.nanoTime();
    }

    @Override
    public void sleep(long arg0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(arg0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("Kafka systemtime interrupted",e);
        }
    }

}
```