# Failure to Produce to Embedded Kafka Broker

Tags: scala, clojure, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to use kafka's `kafka.zk.EmbeddedZookeeper` and a `kafka.server.KafkaServer`returned by `kafka.utils.TestUtils/createServer`, to run a kafka server for test purposes.

But I'm hitting a roadblock where trying to send a message times out, and returns a `KafkaProducer$Future` failure. Below is the kafka version I'm using. And the code below is Clojure interoperating with the Kafka library.

```
[org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.11 "0.10.0.1"]
[org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients "0.10.1.0"]
```

This is how far I get.

- Zookeeper port is randomly assigned (see [here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/test/scala/unit/kafka/zk/EmbeddedZookeeper.scala#L34)).
- Can successfully create a Zookeeper [server](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/test/scala/unit/kafka/utils/TestUtils.scala#L122-L126) and connect to it, using [netcat](https://nmap.org/ncat/).
- Can successfully create a topic.
- Can successfully create a Kafka broker and connect to it, using netcat.
- Step 5, is where the process fails.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324736/error-producing-to-embedded-kafka-queue-after-upgrade-from-0-7-to-0-8-1-1) suggests that it's important to pass in a correct `Time` object. But [MockTime](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/test/scala/unit/kafka/utils/MockTime.scala) looks like a reasonable implementation. Anyone tackled this before?

```
;; 1. Create Zookeeper
(require '[clojure.test :refer :all]
     '[kafkaesque.topics :as kt]
     '[kafkaesque.utils :as ku]
     '[clojure.pprint :refer [pprint]])

(import '[java.nio.file Files]
    '[kafka.zk EmbeddedZookeeper]
    '[kafka.server KafkaServer KafkaConfig]
    '[kafka.utils TestUtils Time MockTime])

(def zk-config {:zkhost "127.0.0.1"})
(def topic-name "client-test")
(def ^EmbeddedZookeeper zkServer (EmbeddedZookeeper.))


;; 2. Create Kafka Broker
(def zk-connect-str (str "127.0.0.1" ":" (.port zkServer)))
(def zku ((ZkUtils/apply (ZkUtils/createZkClient zk-connect-str 10000 8000) false)))
(def brokerhost "127.0.0.1")
(def brokerport "9092")

(def ^KafkaConfig config (KafkaConfig. {"zookeeper.connect" zk-connect-str
                       "broker.id" "0"
                       "log.dirs" (.toString
                           (.toAbsolutePath
                            (Files/createTempDirectory
                             "kafka-" (make-array java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute 0))))
                       "listeners" (str "PLAINTEXT://"  brokerhost  ":"  brokerport)}))

(def ^Time mock (MockTime.))
(def ^KafkaServer kafkaServer (TestUtils/createServer config mock))


;; 3. Create a Topic
(kt/create! zku topic-name 1 1 {})
(kt/topic-exists? zku topic-name)   ;; returns true


;; 4. Create a Producer and ProducerRecord
(def producer-a (kc/producer {"bootstrap.servers" "127.0.0.1:9092"
                 "acks"              "all"
                 "retries"           "0"
                 "batch.size"        "16384"
                 "linger.ms"         "1"
                 "buffer.memory"     "33554432"
                 "key.serializer"    "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
                 "value.serializer"  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"}))

(def message-key "k1")
(def message-value "foobar")
(def record-a (kc/producer-record topic-name 0 message-key message-value))


;; 5. Send a message
(def send-result (kc/send! producer-a record-a))  ;; Times out, and returns a KafkaProducer$Future failure.
```

Comment: It's okay to not specify a Time instance for TestUtils.createServer since it will create a default one. As for the 'times out', could you confirm it is saying getting metadata times out?  Besides, I notice that versions for the client and server do not match. Could you use Kafka of same version to retry?

Comment: @amethystic Crikey, that was it - a version mismatch. *org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.11* **"0.10.0.1"**, versus *org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients* **"0.10.1.0"**. Geez, I was pulling my hair out! I moved all versions to **"0.10.1.0"**, and everything works. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks goes to @amethystic for pointing out my dyslexia :) The problem was a version mismatch. I was using *org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.11* **"0.10.0.1"**, with *org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients* **"0.10.1.0"**.

I moved all versions to **"0.10.1.0"**, and everything works as expected.

Hope this helps.